# Can I create an array of unique_ptr<T[]>(n), n declared at runtime, without looping on the elements?

Tags: c++, arrays, unique-ptr

I'd like to fill a structure that looks like this:

```
unique_ptr<int[]> myArray[10];
```

Each `unique_ptr` is an array of size `n`, defined at runtime but which remains constant.

Is there a way to initialize everything in the declaration of `myArray`? Or at least not have to explicitely loop over each `unique_ptr` in `myArray`?

Because for now the simplest solution I've found is to add:

```
for(auto & it : myArray)
    it.reset(new int[n]);
```

But it feels like with all these cool improvements to C++ there would be a simpler way to initialise an array of 10 arrays of constant size `n`.

I tried something like:

```
generate_n(std::begin(myArray), 10, []{ return std::unique_ptr<int[]>(new int[n]); });
```

But I get an error about implicitely capturing `n`. I have no idea what that means...

Comment: What you seem to want is a pointer to a *vector*. I.e. `std::unique_ptr<std::vector<int>>`.

Comment: `[]{ /**/ });` -> `[n]{ /**/ });` to capture `n`. Why are you avoiding a simple for loop? `std::generate` is a more complicated solution...

Comment: There is nothing shameful about using a single loop to initialize an array.  Keep it  simple.

Comment: The tricky problem here is that `new int(n)` allocates a single `int` initialized with the value of `n` (this also leads to undefined behavior due to mismatching `delete[]` call). Array allocation would look like `new int[n]`

Comment: Also note that pointers to arrays, or vectors, are seldom very useful. Except if you want the ownership semantics of `std::unique_ptr`.

Comment: Apparently, from your comments, the answer seems to be no. And VTT, you're right, I made the change.

Comment: If you are able to change structure littlebit, do this
   `std::vector<std::array> myArray(10, std::array<int, n>());`
I'm not sure if it will work, not tested..
Or exchange std::array for std::vector.. it will work then for sure

Comment: what is the use case for a data structure like this?  it seems like a vector of vector would work.

Comment: @thang: That doesn't guarantee that all the rows stay the same length.  Vector of vectors could work but the proposed approach is better and also should work.

Comment: @Payne: `std::array<int, n>` doesn't allow `n` to vary at runtime.

Comment: how is the proposed approach better than vector of vector?  the proposed approach also doesn't guarantee that all rows are of the same length.  if all rows should be of the same length, maybe a 2dimensional array should be used?

Comment: why not vector<vector<int>> myArray(10,vector<int>(20)) ?  unless there is a reason to add an additional indirection, i would think the proposed approach is worse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a raw arrays of smart pointers to raw arrays which is not C++ idiomatic. IMHO, `std::array<std::vector<int>, 10> MyArray;` would be later easier to use. Anyway, the error message is pretty self explanatory: you use the `n` variable in the lambda function without capturing it. The compiler just requires:

```
generate_n(std::begin(myArray), 10, [n]{ return std::unique_ptr<int[]>(new int[n]); });
```

In fact, the correct way to generate a `unque_ptr` is through `make_unique`, so the above line should be re-written as (thanks to BenVoigt for noticing):

```
generate_n(std::begin(myArray), 10, [n]{ return make_unique<int[]>(n); });
```

Comment: Thank you Serge!! That's exactly what I was looking for! Yeah, once you read a bit about lambda expressions it becomes clearer...